# Local storage using redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage, redux-toolkit

I would like to keep my isAuthenticated state in local storage, so after refreshing the page, the user will be logged in. I tried straightforward, to set it ti true/false in localStorage and to set initial value of my state in redux to this value, but it always sets it to true.

Here's my redux store

```
import { createSlice, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

//MOVEMENTS (doesn't work yet)
const initialMovementsState = {
  movements: [],
};

const movementsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'movements',
  initialState: initialMovementsState,
  reducers: {
    add(state) {
      //nothing yet
    },
    decrement(state) {
      //nothing yet
    },
  },
});

//LOGGING IN/OUT
const initialAuthState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: initialAuthState,
  reducers: {
    login(state) {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
    },
    logout(state) {
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
    },
  },
});

//STORE CONFIGURATION

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    movements: movementsSlice.reducer,
    auth: authSlice.reducer,
  },
});

export const movementsActions = movementsSlice.actions;
export const authActions = authSlice.actions;

export default store;
```

All answers I found are with redux only, not with redux toolkit and I'm kinda fresh to redux, so I'm lost.

Comment: Hey, I'm coming here with an update. Actually nobody in the comments recommended me redux persist, which would totally satisfy me for this issue :D The most up-voted answer is a gem though, so I leave the question for others

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Update October 2022**: You can also use redux-toolkit's `createListenerMiddleware` in versions 1.8 and up, as [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73968086/10431574).

---

Changing `localStorage` is a side-effect so you don't want to do it in your reducer.  A reducer should always be free of side-effects. One way to handle this is with a custom middleware.

### Writing Middleware

Our middleware gets called after every action is dispatched.  If the action is `login` or `logout` then we will change the `localStorage` value.  Otherwise we do nothing.  Either way we pass the action off to the next middleware in the chain with `return next(action)`.

The only difference in the middleware between redux-toolkit and vanilla redux is how we detect the `login` and `logout` actions.  With redux-toolkit the action creator functions include a helpful `match()` function that we can use rather than having to look at the `type`.  We know that an `action` is a login action if `login.match(action)` is true.  So our middleware might look like this:

```
const authMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (authActions.login.match(action)) {
    // Note: localStorage expects a string
    localStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', 'true');
  } else if (authActions.logout.match(action)) {
    localStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', 'false');
  }
  return next(action);
};
```

### Applying Middleware

You will add the middleware to your store in the `configureStore` function.  Redux-toolkit [includes some middleware by default](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware) with enables thunk, immutability checks, and serializability checks.  Right now you are not setting the `middleware` property on your store at all, so you are getting all of the defaults included.  We want to make sure that we keep the defaults when we add our custom middleware.

The `middleware` property can be defined as a function which gets called with the redux-toolkit `getDefaultMiddleware` function.  This allows you to set options for the default middleware, if you want to, while also adding our own.  We will [follow the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#intended-usage) example and write this:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    movements: movementsSlice.reducer,
    auth: authSlice.reducer,
  },
  // Note: you can include options in the argument of the getDefaultMiddleware function call.
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(authMiddleware)
});
```

**Don't do this**, as it will remove all default middleware

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    movements: movementsSlice.reducer,
    auth: authSlice.reducer,
  },
  middleware: [authMiddleware]
});
```

### Syncing State via Middleware

We could potentially streamline our middleware by matching *all* `auth` actions.  We do that by using the [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method on the `action.type` (similar to the examples in the [`addMatcher` docs section](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createreducer#builderaddmatcher) which use `.endswith()`).

Here we find the next state by executing `next(action)` *before* we change `localStorage`.  We set the `localStorage` value to the new state returned by the `auth` slice.

```
const authMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  const result = next(action);
  if ( action.type?.startsWith('auth/') ) {
    const authState = store.getState().auth;
    localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(authState))
  }
  return result;
};
```

Or you can use the [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) package, which does that for you.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for help. It didn't entirely solve my problem, but I was digging through docs and other stack overflow threads - it was successfully add things to my local storage, but I was struggling how to 'send' it back to my state. But it was huge help, thank you!

Answer (score 19):

In the meantime I've written the logic for movements and wanted to keep all my state in the local storage. The answer of Linda Paiste was very helpful (and kudos for such a long and straightforward answer!), but I was struggling with sending my local storage back to my redux state. Here's the working solution:

```
import { createSlice, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import dummyItems from '../helpers/dummyItems';

const initialMovementsState = {
  movements: dummyItems,
};

const movementsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'movements',
  initialState: initialMovementsState,
  reducers: {
    add(state, action) {
      state.movements = [action.payload, ...state.movements];
    },
    delete(state, action) {
      const id = action.payload;
      state.movements = state.movements.filter(mov => mov.id !== id);
    },
  },
});

//AUTHORIZATION
const initialAuthState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: initialAuthState,
  reducers: {
    login(state) {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
    },
    logout(state) {
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
    },
  },
});

//MIDDLEWARE
const localStorageMiddleware = ({ getState }) => {
  return next => action => {
    const result = next(action);
    localStorage.setItem('applicationState', JSON.stringify(getState()));
    return result;
  };
};

const reHydrateStore = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('applicationState') !== null) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('applicationState')); // re-hydrate the store
  }
};

//STORE CONFIGURATION
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    movements: movementsSlice.reducer,
    auth: authSlice.reducer,
  },
  preloadedState: reHydrateStore(),
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(localStorageMiddleware),
});

export const movementsActions = movementsSlice.actions;
export const authActions = authSlice.actions;

export default store;
```

Comment: `localeStorage` is not available at the time when calling `reHydrateStore` function. @AniaKowalska

Comment: Of course it is, the above snippet is valid and working code as expected

Comment: if you server render react app; `localStorage` **will not** be available, I tested it on `nextjs`.

Comment: Is it a case here though? The problem was solved with this code snippet

Answer (score 0):

In Redux Toolkit, you can simply create a **Middleware** which save state data in storage, and you can create one more function for **preloadedState** to load data in to store when page reloads.

```
//MIDDLEWARE
const cartMiddleware = ({ getState }) => {
  return (next) => (action) => {
    const result = next(action);
    localStorage.setItem("cartData", JSON.stringify(getState()));
    return result;
  };
};
```

Get data from storage

```
const reHydrateStore = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("cartData") !== null) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartData")); // re-hydrate the store
  }
};
```

Now this **middleware** and **preloadedState** you need to include in store configuration to work as middleware for your state and load state respectively.

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: cartSliceReducer,
  preloadedState: reHydrateStore(),
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(cartMiddleware),
});
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import userReducer from '../userSlices';

const store =  configureStore({

    reducer:{
        user:userReducer,
    },
    preloadedState:loadFromLocalStorage()
});

function saveToLocalStorage(state){

    try{
      const serialState = JSON.stringify(state)
      localStorage.setItem("reduxStore",serialState)
    }catch(e){
      console.warn(e);
    }
  }
  
  function loadFromLocalStorage(){

    try{
      const serialisedState = localStorage.getItem("reduxStore");
      if(serialisedState === null) return undefined;
      return JSON.parse(serialisedState);
    }catch(e){
      console.warn(e);
      return undefined;
    }
  }

  store.subscribe(()=>saveToLocalStorage(store.getState()));
    
export default store;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You must `dispatch` the `login` or `logout` action to actually changes your state in the redux store!

Comment: Just simple use `dispatch(login())` or `dispatch(logout())`. And you should change `isAuthenticated` in `localStorage` after you dispatch your action.

Comment: I tried like this (like I mentioned in my question) and it doesn't work. It always sets it to true after refreshing.