# Redux Toolkit save state to local storage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux-toolkit and I'm trying to save my state to local storage after each update of the store without using any third-parties libraries. The reason for this is redux-persist is no longer updated and I don't know any good alternative. After lots of time looking for solution, I came up with using `createListenerMiddleware`.

```
import { configureStore, createListenerMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import counterSlice, { decrement, increment } from "../Slices/counterSlice";

const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware()
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
    actionCreator: increment,
    effect: () => (
        localStorage.setItem('count', JSON.stringify(store.getState().counter))
    )
})
const listenerMiddleware2 = createListenerMiddleware()
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
    actionCreator: decrement,
    effect: () => (
        localStorage.setItem('count', JSON.stringify(store.getState().counter))
    )
})
const counterState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('count') || "null")
export const store = configureStore({
    preloadedState: {
        counter: counterState === null ? { value: 0 } : counterState
    },
    reducer: {
        counter: counterSlice
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(listenerMiddleware2.middleware, listenerMiddleware.middleware)
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

Could someone tell me if this is a good idea, and if not, is there any other way of doing it properly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 16):

You are on the right track but there are a few changes:

### Accessing State

Rather than using the `store` variable directly to call `getState()`, you should access the `getState()` function from the arguments of the `effect` callback.

```
effect: (action: Action, listenerApi: ListenerApi) => void | Promise<void>
```

Your `effect` function gets called with two arguments: the `action` which triggered the effect and the `listenerApi` object, which gives you access to `getState()` and [many other utilities](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#listener-api).

The listener middleware is not aware of the TypeScript type for the store so you need to make it aware somehow.  One way to do this is with an inline `as` assertion on the `listenerApi.getState()` call.

```
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  actionCreator: increment,
  effect: (action, listenerApi) =>
    localStorage.setItem("count", JSON.stringify((listenerApi.getState() as RootState).counter))
});
```

You can also follow the [TypeScript Usage](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#typescript-usage) section of the docs and use the `TypedStartListening` utility type.

### Handling Multiple actions

You don't need multiple listener middleware instances because you can attach many listeners to the same middleware.  Simple call `startListening` multiple times on the same `listenerMiddleware` variable.

However in this instance one `startListening` call is all that you need!  Both of your cases already have the same `effect` callback.  But we need to be able to match both `increment` and `decrement` actions.  There are [a few different ways](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#startlistening) that a listener can detect matching actions.  Instead of using `actionCreator`, which can only match a single action, we will use the `matcher` property.  We create a matcher function with a little help from the [`isAnyOf` utility](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities).

Our final middleware looks like this:

```
import { createListenerMiddleware, isAnyOf } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { decrement, increment } from "./slice";
import type { RootState } from "./index";

export const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware();
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  matcher: isAnyOf(increment, decrement),
  effect: (action, listenerApi) =>
    localStorage.setItem(
      "count",
      JSON.stringify((listenerApi.getState() as RootState).counter)
    )
});
```

##### [Complete CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-persisted-state-via-localstorage-tj20me?file=/src/store/middleware.ts)